# Using mysql_fetch_assoc in a while loop with extra condition

Tags: php

Why is $row empty when I apply the while loop with mysql_fetch_assoc with an extra condition, but when the extra condition is not there, returns something, is this logical?

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) 
        && $gen->getMailsSent() < 499) {
     //blah blah
}
```

In the above code, the compiler enteres the loop, but $row is empty

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
     //blah blah
}
```

In this one, the compiler still enteres the loop, but then $row returns something, this to me i dont get and is not logical, can someone please explain why this occurs?

Comment: can you show the rest of your code? Can't tell much about it from that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while (($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
        && $gen->getMailsSent() < 499) {
     //blah blah
}
```

Try this. Your problem is precedence - you actually tell it to

```
$row = (mysql_fetch_assoc($result) && $gen->getMailsSent() < 499)
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php

"&&" comes before "=" in the list, so it gets evaluated first.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
while (($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
        && $gen->getMailsSent() < 499) {
     //blah blah
}
```

actually it shouldn't be empty, it should be a boolean.

Answer (score 0):

```
Use while loop like this:

while (($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))  && ($gen->getMailsSent() < 499)) {
    code goes here..
}
```

hope this will help..