# Joinning two sql tables and displaying them

Tags: php, sql

Please bear with me as this is my first post.

I am attempting to display info from sql tables. I already checked my sql code in sql admin and it gives me the right table I need but php is not giving me the results and giving me this:
Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\Program\displaybook.php on line 91

I believe something is wrong with my SELECT statement or the way I am writing the statement in general.

**ratings:**

```
user_id | ISBN      | Score | Description

11      | 425232204 |   5   | This is my favorite book!!

7       | 425232204 |   4   | I liked it.
```

**users:**

```
user_id |   user_email    | user_first | user_middle | user_last

7       | jerry@gmail.com |    Jerry   |      W      |  Smith

11      | tpott78@att.net |   Tristan  |      S      |  Potter
```

Query:

```
$sql = "SELECT * 
            FROM ratings 
            INNER JOIN users 
            ON users.'user_id' = ratings.'user_id' 
            WHERE ISBN = '$isbn'";
    $results = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $resultCheck = mysqli_num_rows($results);
    $count = 0;
    if ($resultCheck > 0){
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results) && $count < 5) {
            $count += 1;
            echo "<p>" . $row['user_first']  . "  " . $row['user_last'] . "     " . $row['Score'] . "     " . $row['Description'] ."</p>";
        }
    }
```

Sorry I forgot that info that someone brought up in commits. Yes i have an include header file at the top of the php code that also connects to the db. I know this works cause I have some other SELECTS that are working fine.

Comment: Your query is fine.  This is a PHP problem.

Comment: Oops...I missed that :-). ...voting to close as typo question.  I only checked the names of the join columns, which are correct.

Comment: @Syscall Actually, it should be `u.user_id`, _without_ single quotes, which are wrong, and backticks, which are also bad.

Comment: Change query like this:- `$sql = "SELECT * 
            FROM ratings 
            INNER JOIN users 
            ON users.user_id = ratings.user_id 
            WHERE ISBN = $isbn";` and you will good to go

Comment: okay @AlivetoDie that solved the warning error but it isn't displaying the data which is a slightly bigger problem as I don't know why the data isn't being shown.

Comment: Then you should open a new question for that.  This thread is most likely abandoned at this point.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16786898/using-mysql-fetch-assoc-in-a-while-loop-with-extra-condition,  your problem is precedence.